# Qt Designer: Widget's layout borders visibility

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qt-designer

Sometimes it's very useful to see cells of layout(grid layout). If I place layout element on the widget and then work with that layout - it's ok. But in case when I use widget as a layout - it's, I guess, impossible to see red line borders of layout.

So, Is it possible to turn on layout view (I mean red line borders) on the parent widget in Qt Designer?

Comment: Explain better Please.

Comment: I think it is not possible, at least I couldn't find a solution for it, but maybe someone else got an idea... You could use the workaround of using the grid layout inside a vertical layout of the parent widget. That's what I did back then.